# Environmental variables only accessible during development, how to make this work after deploying website? (GatsbyJS project)

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, gatsby

I have finished building a simple resume/portfolio website using GatsbyJS in development.

I am using three environment variables (env var) to store my social media links (email/mobile/linkedin), as I will be displaying them in my React frontend.

I am storing all my env var(s) inside `.env.development` file in the root.

I am using the `env-cmd` package for accessing the env var(s).

In my `package.json` file, I modified the `develop` script to the following:

```
"develop": "env-cmd -f .env.development gatsby develop",
```

^ With that, I am able to access the environmental variables in my front end.

e.g.

```
<div>{process.env.EMAIL}</div>
```

I am using Netlify for deployment, and I tried putting env vars within Netlify after building it, but it didn't work.

So I think the problem is stems from the env vars being only accessible during development, so my question is, how do I make sure they are accessible after deploying the website (in production)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are available on build/compile. In order to use them on the client you should create a `.env.production` (I was using `dotenv`) when building, you can place it for instance on top of `gatsby-config.js`

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const VARS = [
  'TEST'
]

function createProdEnv () {
  var content = ''

  VARS.map(varName => {
    content += varName + '=' + process.env[varName] + '\n'
  })

  fs.writeFileSync('./.env.production', content)
}

module.exports = createProdEnv
```

And call it from `gatsby-config.js`

```
createProdEnv()
```

Comment: Would that three env var inside `.env.development` be in `.env.production` too?

Comment: Yes, but you should create .env.production on build time, that's when they're available from Netlify. From: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/hosting-on-netlify/ "Advanced build settings: If our site needs enviromnent variables to build, we can spectify them by clicking on Show advanced and then the New Variable button."

Comment: I deployed on Netlify and created new variables like that link suggested. Is that not creating `.env.production` in build time? Or do I need to create that file locally first, then matching it in Netlify?

Comment: Add them to Netlify, that means you have access to them when deploying. So when you deploy you must create a `.env.production file` as I showed in the example with `createProdEnv()`

Comment: I am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/8t0vNu2fCCM?t=15976, and he didn't use `.env.development` nor `.env.production` right before deploying, yet he can still access his env var, why is that?

Comment: Can't watch the vid rn sry, but you've to understand that those variables are only available on build/deploy time, that's why I create a .env.production 'on the fly' when building.

Answer (score 0):

So after reading the docs again: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/

I simply prefixed all my env var with `GATSBY_` in my `.env` file, just like `REACT_` in create-react-app. I didn't use `.env.development` nor `.env.production` files, simply just a `.env` file.

Then in Netlify I input the same env var, and it worked!

I am not sure if this is the optimal solution, so if there is a better way to do this, please share!